# How to toggle the viewport of webpage using a button in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, viewport

Im trying to make my website change view from mobile to desktop view using a button in javascript

```
const handleClick = () => {

      const viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]")
      viewport.setAttribute(
         "content",
         "width=200px, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=0",
      )
}
```

I am using this code and it changes the viewport in html when I inspect using chrome but the screen is not changing

Comment: The viewport values are already set and the document loaded before you can click a button to set viewport values. What are you trying to achieve? As this is not going to work...

Comment: @RenevanderLende Im want to  preview my website in mobile view and desktop view using a button instead using the inspect element in chrome ,just check window.resizeTo but its also disabled

Comment: You need to set the `width` and `height` of `<body>` to the layout you need, changing the meta will have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you cant use document.queryselector directly in react js like we do in html, instead you have to use useRef and ref for accessing DOM elements.